# Should I have new entity for each kind of database query?

Tags: java, database, architecture, entity

Is there any best practice to avoid the immense amount of DTOs and entities?

Right now my App has some entity and DTO for each database table. However because the queries from the User interface
are varied a lot I created new entities and DTOs for each of the queries, which led to DTO-Entity hell.

**Take this example:**

Despite our Application is very simple and has only two database tables:

- *Person table with id,name,age,vehicle_id;*
- *Vehicle table with id,brand_name, speed, price;*

The starting point is that we have only the following classes:

- *PersonEntity, PersonDto, VehicleEntity, VehicleDto*

The user can get Persons,Vehicles by id and name.
So far so simple.

**But we got a new requirement:**

The user want to query the average vehicle price by person names. 
(ie. The vehicles owned by all of the Franks have an avegare price of 25.213$)
So on the ui side we need one object: 
*PersonGrouppedAvgPrice with fields of personName and averagePrice*

**I found the following solutions:**

1. So either we fetch all the Person with the given names and the corresponding cars from the db
   and return it to the UI (and the calculation will happen on the ui side),
   which leads to unnecessary network traffic and memory consumption,but at least we aren't forced to create new entities.
2. We still fetch everything as above from the db and make the calculation on the server side on DTO level. In this case
   we still aren't forced to create new entity but we have to create the new DTO. Network traffic is lowered but memory is still
   high.
3. We make the corresponding logic on the DAO level with query like:
   *select p.name,avg(v.price) from person_table as p inner join ...etc* 
   In this case we get back only the necessary information which the most efficient but in this case we need the new DTOs and entities.

I have used the third one.
But because of the various UI query the number of new classes escalated to a level on which it will become unmaintainable in the future. 
For 20 database tables I have had to create ~4-4 Entity and DTO, which is ~160 classes.

Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Why should more queries == more **entities**?  Wouldn't you only need more _entities_ if you added more database tables?  More DTOs for more queries, yes, but not (I wouldn't think) more entities

Comment: @Kevin Anderson
point 2, You would fetch more data from the db than you actually need (I fetch to entity and then convert to dto)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Point 3 is the right approach for a RDMBS. You should use queries to perform this work in the database as transferring all the table data from database server to application server will be inefficient.

For each custom query, that requires a specialized projection, you might end up with additional DTO classes. That is not necessarily wrong, it will help with writing unit tests. There are few ways to reduce the number of DTO classes e.g. by using tuples [as described in this article](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-projection-query-to-a-dto-with-jpa-and-hibernate/).

Comment: And don't forget the possibility of re-using DTO classes for similar queries.  If you have several queries that all begin with `select p.name,avg(v.price) FROM ...`, for example, you can use the same DTO class with all of them.